# Keras - Why is the accuracy of my CNN model not being affected by the hyper-parameters?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer, grid-search

As the title clearly describes, the accuracy of my simple CNN model is not being affected by the hyper-parameters or even the existence of layers such as `Dropout`, and `MaxPooling`. I implemented the model using `Keras`. What could be the reason behind this odd situation? I added the regarding part of the code below:

```
input_dim = X_train.shape[1]
nb_classes = Y_train.shape[1]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(input_dim, 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(40, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

p.s. The input data (`X_train` and `X_test`) contains vectors which were reproduced by `Word2Vec`. The output is binary.

Edit: You may find a sample training log below:

Sample training log:

```
Train on 3114 samples, validate on 347 samples
Epoch 1/10
 - 1s - loss: 0.6917 - accuracy: 0.5363 - val_loss: 0.6901 - val_accuracy: 0.5476
Epoch 2/10
 - 1s - loss: 0.6906 - accuracy: 0.5369 - val_loss: 0.6896 - val_accuracy: 0.5476
Epoch 3/10
 - 1s - loss: 0.6908 - accuracy: 0.5369 - val_loss: 0.6895 - val_accuracy: 0.5476
Epoch 4/10
 - 1s - loss: 0.6908 - accuracy: 0.5369 - val_loss: 0.6903 - val_accuracy: 0.5476
Epoch 5/10
 - 1s - loss: 0.6908 - accuracy: 0.5369 - val_loss: 0.6899 - val_accuracy: 0.5476
Epoch 6/10
 - 1s - loss: 0.6909 - accuracy: 0.5369 - val_loss: 0.6901 - val_accuracy: 0.5476
Epoch 7/10
 - 1s - loss: 0.6905 - accuracy: 0.5369 - val_loss: 0.6896 - val_accuracy: 0.5476
Epoch 8/10
 - 1s - loss: 0.6909 - accuracy: 0.5369 - val_loss: 0.6897 - val_accuracy: 0.5476
Epoch 9/10
 - 1s - loss: 0.6905 - accuracy: 0.5369 - val_loss: 0.6892 - val_accuracy: 0.5476
Epoch 10/10
 - 1s - loss: 0.6909 - accuracy: 0.5369 - val_loss: 0.6900 - val_accuracy: 0.5476
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have multi-class classification, right?

Then your loss is not appropriate: you should use '`categorical_crossentropy`' not '`mean_squared_error`'.

Also, try adding several Conv+Drop+MaxPool (3 sets) in order to clearly verify the robustness of your network.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `mse` as the loss for a multi-class classification problem. It's still a valid loss function. It's only that `categorical_crossentropy` performs better in most cases.

Comment: The accuracy is still the same.

Comment: Between, I'm working a binary classification problem as my target classes are `0`, and `1`.

Comment: You are right, mse is not an incorrect one, that's why I edited the text answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change the last layer to

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

You also need to change the loss function to

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: The accuracy still stays the same.

Comment: what does your dataset look like then, I think that you have done something wrong in the data preprocessing, or your X isn't related to y. I find that it is not normal also that your input shape is (input_dim, 1) it is like if you are trying to classify a single words into one of two classes. Is that really what you are doing ?

Comment: Actually what I am working on is extracting features of malicious and benign Android apps in order to classify them into two classes. So, the features are basically Strings, and I'm constructing feature vectors. The `input_dim` is the size of each vector. The input data has a shape of `(3451, 100)`.

Comment: You have mentionned that ou have used word2vec to construct X, can you precise how you have done this. Can you also precise if your features are just a list of words, or are they more like sentences.

Comment: No, they are actually methods, classes, and some terms specific to Android. The word vector feature extraction was handled through the Gensim package.

Comment: Well this justifies why your model is giving poor results, in fact word2vec maps the english word (if you are using the english version of word2vec) or any other language, to some pretraiend embeddings (i.e. vectors). So those embeddings gives some sort of representation of the words in that language, if you want to use the same words with names of classes or methods it wont work good, because they are not commonly used words, and perhaps a lot of them are out of vocabulary. I propose that you change the feature extraction you have done (I continue in the next comment)

Comment: The first solution you can try is to train your own embedding, but before doing this need first to do some preporcessing on you textual data (tokenize, lemmatize, transform to indexes....). You can then use the embedding layer in keras then add an LSTM on top of it or any other reccurent network. For now I am assuming that your data is a script, is that really the case ? Can you also give some details about what you are classifying ? maybe an example of one of those objects you want to classify

Comment: Of course the accuracy stays the same. Softmax + Dense(2) + CategoricalCrossEntropy is the same with Sigmoid + Dense(1) + BinaryCrossentropy

Comment: @TimbusCalin Yes, but the loss function used was "mse". However the fact that the accuracy doesn't go down is more related to the data used.